# Some people can access and nslookup my website but some others cant?

Tags: nslookup

I am having a very weird problem with my server. Most people and myself can access normally without problem but some others report they cant and the only way they can access is through proxies and so. If i perform a nslookup in my domain i can see the server IP and all that, but those people receive a time out request unknown error. This is my domain (please look at the image):[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X2hA.png)

What can be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a common environment where the people cannot access your server? What OS/webserver are you running? The site loads up fine for me. Is your firewall blocking any IP blocks for any reason?

Comment: Not actually, all of them have different OS, browsers, are in different countries, ISPs etc.

Comment: I'm curious of the answer to this as I do not have one. I'm +1'ing this question. All I can think of is the end user's ISP having something to do with it.

Comment: Maybe they use IPv6

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone using ipv6 without support for ipv4. ipv6 isn't widely accepted yet.

Comment: Is it possible to know wheter a user has a IPv6?

Comment: Probably, depending on your webserver you can probably set something to make sure the IP of the client connecting is logged. thats assuming that your not using a CDN, then some additional steps would propbably come into play.

Comment: What about if the user visits whatsmip.com or so, would they know?

Comment: http://whatismyipv6address.com/ the page states that if there machine uses ipv6 over ipv4 than the ipv6 address will be shown. if not then the ipv4 address will be shown. or. http://ipv6.whatismyv6.com/ if that page fails then the user is not using ipv6